# Laravel has on where function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm currently using this function to gather all of my users with a relationship

```
    $users = users::with(array('statusCurrent' => function($query)
    {
        $query->where('status.status', 'in');
        $query->orderBy('status.date', 'DESC');
    }));
    $users = $users->get();
```

This returns both of my users, and if `status = 'in'` then it returns the relationship aswell, but if `status = 'out'` it still returns the row, but with `status_current = null`.

Basically I want to ignore the user completely if the arguments inside the `with` query builder function are not true.

I have tried `$candidates = $candidates->has('statusCurrent')->get();` to try and only get results where the relationship is not null, but it still returns users where the StatusCurrent relationship is null.

How do I do it so that foreach of the users, if whatever arguments I pass into the `with(array('statusCurrent' => function(){})` are not true, it is ignored completely?

**EDIT**

Users Model

```
public function statusCurrent(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Status', 'user_id', 'id')->orderBy('date', 'desc')->limit(1);
}
```

The user can have many status', but the `StatusCurrent` relationship is meant to return their 1 most recent status based on the `status.date`

Comment: try without `status.` like `->where('status', 'in');` and 
       `->orderBy('date', 'DESC');`

Comment: Does the user's *latest* status have to be `in`?

Answer (score 0):

You need `whereHas` to filter out users based on their relationship

```
$users = users::with(array('statusCurrent' => function($query)
    {  
        $query->orderBy('status.date', 'DESC');
    }))
    ->whereHas('statusCurrent', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'in');
    })
    ->get();
```

See [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: This is still returning both users, I have edited the question and included the model relationship if it helps.